# TypeError in MySQL - Python OOP program

Tags: python, mysql

I'm starting to practice MySQL basics with Python OOP. I started with basic point of sale and I'm getting an error: TypeError: 'str' object is not callable, which I don't know how to solve. It's in spanish but I think it's understandable.

This is my program:

```
import pymysql as sql

class Database:
    def __init__(self):

        self.conexion = sql.connect(
            host = 'localhost',
            user = 'root',
            password = '',
            db = 'PythonBD'
        )

        print('\n ¡Conexión con base de datos establecida con éxito!\n')

        self.miCursor = self.conexion.cursor()

    def crearTabla(self):
        self.miCursor.execute = ('''
            CREATE TABLE productos (
                id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
                nombre VARCHAR(20) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
                precio INT NOT NULL,
                stock INT DEFAULT 'SIN STOCK'
            )
        ''')

        print('\n ¡Tabla creada con éxito!')

    def insertarProductos(self, nombre, precio, stock):
        self.miCursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO productos VALUES({nombre}, {precio}, {stock})") 
        self.conexion.commit()

        print('\n ¡Productos agregados con éxito!')
    
    def seleccionProductos(self, id):
        self.miCursor.execute(f'SELECT * FROM productos WHERE id = {id}')
        self.peticion = self.miCursor.fetchall()
        for i in self.peticion:
            print('Nombre:', i[1], 'Precio:', i[2], 'Stock:', i[3])

        self.conexion.commit()
    
    def eliminarProductos(self, id):
        self.miCursor.execute(f'DELETE FROM productos WHERE id = {id}')
        self.conexion.commit()

        print('\n ¡Producto eliminado con éxito!')
    
    def actualizarProductos(self, id, precio):
        self.miCursor.execute(f'UPDATE TABLE productos SET precio = {precio} WHERE id = {id}')
        self.conexion.commit()

        print('\n ¡Producto actualizado con éxito!')
    
    def borrarTabla(self):
        self.miCursor.execute('DROP TABLE productos')
        self.conexion.commit()

        print('\n ¡Tabla borrada con éxito!')

    def cerrarConexion(self):
        self.conexion.close()

database = Database()

#database.borrarTabla()
database.crearTabla()
database.insertarProductos('Manzana', 990, 5)
database.insertarProductos('Plátano', 990, 10)
database.cerrarConexion()
```

Comment: Please show the traceback that shows the error and the line it's happening on.

Comment: The traceback is: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Pruebas Python\BBDD Python\Ejemplo 1 BBDD.py", line 66, in <module>
    database.insertarProductos('Manzana', 990, 5)
  File "d:\Pruebas Python\BBDD Python\Ejemplo 1 BBDD.py", line 29, in insertarProductos
    self.miCursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO productos VALUES('{nombre}', {precio}, {stock})")
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your traceback trace complained about this line:

```
self.miCursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO productos VALUES('{nombre}', {precio}, {stock})")
    TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Which would indicate that `self.miCursor.execute` is a `str` type and you're trying to call it as a method.

So if you look at the rest of the code, you have a bug in your `crearTable` method:

```py
def crearTabla(self):
    self.miCursor.execute = ('''
        CREATE TABLE productos (
            id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
            nombre VARCHAR(20) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
            precio INT NOT NULL,
            stock INT DEFAULT 'SIN STOCK'
        )
    ''')
```

You assigned `self.miCursor.execute` to be a `str` with that `CREATE TABLE` statement. Remove the assignment and your code should work:

```py
def crearTabla(self):
    self.miCursor.execute('''
        CREATE TABLE productos (
            id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
            nombre VARCHAR(20) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
            precio INT NOT NULL,
            stock INT DEFAULT 'SIN STOCK'
        )
    ''')
```